# Перестала работать Anaconda на windows

Tags: anaconda

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как её решить:
На компьютер установил анаконду. Все работало, пользовался какое-то время,  но потом решил поэксперементировать и установил PyCharm и thonny. Посмотрел обе ide и решил вернуться в анаконду (понравилось пользоваться jupiter notebook). А анаконда работать перестала. Начала выдавать какие-то ошибки. Я переустановил ее. Установка прошла успешно, но ничего не установилось (navigator's нет, юпитера нет)

Comment: "Какие-то ошибки" - это какие?

Comment: Уже не вспомню, это было 2 недели назад. Это глупо, но я не загуглил тогда номер ошибки.